# how to make transformed element appear over positioned element?

Tags: html, css

I have [this setup](http://plnkr.co/edit/zC6fffprGUs0wJeTPO38?p=preview):

```
   <style>
      .wrapper {
        position: relative;
        z-index:1;
        width: 100px;
        background: yellow;
        min-height: 70px;
      }

      .inner {
        background: blue;
        width: 100px;
        min-height: 70px;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="wrapper"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>  
  </body>
```

The `wrapper` div overlaps the `inner` div. They both create stacking contexts. Yet if the `inner` div had its own stacking context created by positioning I could control its stacking context with `z-index`, but since its stacking context is created by `transform` how can I make it overlap the `wrapper` div?

Comment: Is removing `z-index` from a wrapper div styling an option?

Comment: Well, this is exploring question :). I added it there in the first place to simulate a situation.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is adding `z-index` (with the value the same or greater than of `.wrapper` element) and `position:relative` to `.inner` element styling:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    /* ... */
}

.inner {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    /* ... */
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/yrjHEbRFNKIQRvdhB6pP?p=preview) Another (rather obvious) approach is removing `z-index: 1` definition from the `.wrapper` styling - but I guess that's not an option.

Comment: Thanks, adding positioning is indeed an option. I was thinking there was something else since transformed elements are usually used for animations and they ought to be above others.